# Visual С# TreeView с колонками в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

В Visual Studio на С# нужен компонент на форме вроде TreeView, но только с поддержкой колонок, как на скрине. В интернете нашел несколько примеров, однако они громоздкие и трудно встраиваемые. Нужно что-то попроще, или аналог этого. Или можно ли как-то склеить вместе с treeview-ром какой-то другой компонент? WinForms

[image: скрин]

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: WinForms, реализовываю всё на стандартных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [TreeViewAdv for .Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/)
- [пример с CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeWithColumns.aspx)
- [еще один пример с CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/extendedlistviews.aspx)
- [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html):

[image: ObjectListView sample]

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, я гуглом тоже умею пользоваться, видел эти все. Проблема заключается в добавлении к проекту

Comment: @ВладиславКазючиц что конкретно не получается?

Comment: То ли я что-то не правильно делаю, то ли так и есть. Именно добавление базы данных с компонентом, или решения. не получается добавить конкретно компонент нужных. В этих ссылка есть примеры, однако там уже готовые формы со встроенным компонентом. приходиться как-то выдирать его оттуда. Просто я таким делом никогда не занимался, вот и испытываю трудности.